# Not Acceptable An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security

Tags: mysql, laravel, apache, form-helpers

Not Acceptable!

An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.

Not Acceptable!

An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.

```
        {{ Form::label('Bangla name', 'Bangla Name') }}

        {{ Form::text('bangla_name','<i class="fas fa-file-signature"></i>', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change input field `bangla_name` to generic `name`. if you are using apache, update your .htaccess file with following.

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Everywhere I look, this is the answer, yet it doesn't work.